# Difference between storing references and objects?

Tags: java, arrays, reference

What is the difference between

```
Player player1 = new Player("John");
players[0] = player1;
```

and

```
players[0] = new Player("John");
```

From my understanding the first one is storing a reference, and the second is storing an object. Am I wrong? Does it make a difference? Which one is better practice?

Comment: There is no difference unless you want to use the Player object further on in the same code scope.

Comment: They are absolutely the same. In the first one, in case of further use, you can use the player1 reference, in the second one you have to access the array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first one, you are storing a reference to `player 1`. This gives you the flexibility to call any methods stored in `player 1` prior to referencing it in your array. The second option just means that the object only resides within your array and so you would have to call a method directly, such as `player[0].run()`.

As for which is a better practice, it simply depends on what you intend to do with the object. If you need to modify it prior to creating a reference in an array, use the first snippet. If you simply need a to instantiate a large number of player objects, I would just use a for loop that creates an array of players directly.

Answer (score 0):

you will this if you later want change or reference the player1 in your code and if you do not want to change or need player1 in your code you can directly assign the player1 at zero indexes

and both one is a good practice as your usage.

- Summary

  1. approach create a pointer to the player1 which can later be used
  2. directly store in an array without having reference to player1

Answer (score 0):

In the first part. First create a new instance that is stored separately in a variable, for later assign it on the array.

The second part. The new instance is stored directly on array.

There isn't wrong on the code.

On my opinion, second part is better that first part.